# In Magento after installing extension Admin panel in unable to load

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.6, magento

As I have assigned to work on magento, according to our requirement i tried to install Arabic extension for magento. The extension got successfully installed. Later on refreshing the admin panel, it shows the URL not found. The Stores FrontEnd CMS home page is loading, But when Iclick on any products, it shows again URL not found..

How can i solve this...

Comment: Did you try disabling the module from /app/etc/modules/xyz_abc.xml? Did you check your error log? Is the 'url not found' a magento or server error?

Comment: error is: 

Not Found

The requested URL /magento/admin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at vittimgr.vitti.co Port 80

Comment: The is going to end up being an issue with server configuration. Magento is technically trying to navigate to www.yoursite.com/index.php/admin (at least i fought with that problem setting up nginx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When diagnosing things like this, try the following..

1. Delete (or move to another folder) files in /var/www/var/cache
2. Delete (or move to another folder) files in /tmp
3. From a shell, run

   /var/www/shell$ php indexer.php --reindexall

You've just manually cleared your caches and re indexed your data. 
See if your system comes back to life.

Comment: I have executed 3rd step also.. but still the same problem ... 404 error.Not Found

The requested URL /magento/admin was not found on this server.

Comment: I noticed you marked my answer as the solution. Did you get the problem solved?

Comment: yes..problem was fixed, but the arabic extension didnt work.. it just shows every page in english

Answer (score 0):

For me I was redirected to wrong URL from MagentoConnect after installation of extension.

**My admin URL**: <-hostname->/index.php/admin

**Redirected To**: <-hostname->/admin

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when I added extension manually. I could find the issue when checked via shell command and it returned missing table error. This is issue happened when I installed module manually.