# Not able to edit contents in magento from backend after a installing modules

Tags: php, magento

I have site build in Magento 1.7

I have installed a new shipping module Bpost through magento connect. When I installed that, it raised the error that, it is already existing plugin. After that when I accessed the site, the maintenance flag was active.

When I removed the maintenance flag and checked the site, everything seems to be working fine in the front-end. But I am not able to add or edit contents from the back-end. Click is not detecting in the existing lists of contents and when I click on add new (for cms block, page etc) the new section appears, but no action is performed while clicking save.

Why is this happening ? How can I resolve this issue ?

I recreated the site with my backup files to a new location. After that removed all the existing plugins and installed all the plugins. At that time all seems to be working fine. After that I have edited the header.phtml file and added some additional script.

The script was for getting contents and displaying it using script. After that when I run the site and went to backend everything again went to non editable mode. Now I am not able to click or edit any cms contents in the site of static blocks, products etc.

Why is this happening ? How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the problem comes from a javascript with an error that blocks the rest of the javascript. All buttons use javascript to fire events. With firebug or something similar, check which error is raised in the admin javascript and try to fix it. Using the solution that Niraj Jani gave about disabling module is a good way to check if it is really the module that blocks the javascript. If the problem is linked with prototype, it can come from the definition of blocks in php, the design template or layout...

Comment: Thanks. It was a problem with Javascript. It worked :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried after claering cache?

Take Look at below link and its answer,
[In Magento after installing extension Admin panel in unable to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238241/in-magento-after-installing-extension-admin-panel-in-unable-to-load)

1. Delete (or move to another folder) files in /var/www/var/cache
2. Delete (or move to another folder) files in /tmp
3. From a shell, run
   /var/www/shell$ php indexer.php --reindexall

You've just manually cleared your caches and re indexed your data. See if your system comes back to life.

Comment: if still having problem disable module by chnging <active>true</active> to <active>false</active> in app/etc/modules/YOURMODULENAME.xml